# Как игнорировать регистр при проверке строки на наличие в списке?

Tags: python, массивы

Код для примера:

```
question = input("Столица Англии? ")
answer = ["Лондон"]

if question in answer:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Если пользователь отправит "Лондон", будет True, а если "лондон", будет False. Как игнорировать регистр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте метод `lower`:

```
question = input("Столица Англии? ")
answer = ["Лондон"]
answer = [a.lower() for a in answer]

if question.lower() in answer:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Только список answer нужно будет предварительно тоже к нижнему регистру привести.

Comment: @Xander, спасибо. исправил

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
question = input("Столица Англии?").lower()
answer = [x.lower() for x in ["Лондон"]]


if question in answer:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```